# How to pass query parameters value as parameter from CMD using talend ESB6.3.1

Tags: mongodb, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio for ESB ver.6.3.1 and created the jobs which is used to pull the data from ALM to MongoDB.In that i used tRESTClient with query parameter(date) for pulling data from ALM & tMongoDBOutput for inserting ALM data. After that i've build the job & imported into eclipse as a java project. I tried to run the program with option of 'Run as Java Application'.It is working fine.

The above job i gave query parameter value directly like '`tRESTClient --> Basic settings --> Query parameters --> name = "query" & value = "{last-modified[>=(2017-04-19 13:02:15)]}" '`, so this job will pull the records based on the query parameters value. 
Now i generated the eclipse talend job as a runnable jar file & trying to pass query parameter value from CMD as a parameter value. 
[image]

How to pass query parameters value as parameter from CMD?

Answer (score 0):

In windows command promote you can write the following command form. 
for example if you have a jar file named test.jar and you have two parameters name & query, then you can pass the command as

```
javaw -jar test.jar -n 'name' -q 'your query'
```

Then you can handle these two parameters i.e name and query in your main method.